# Always on right clickable icon in right of listview

Tags: android, android-listview, overlay

I want to put a click-able gift icon in the left of Listview like this...![image]

I googled never find any solution for this. . Any help or suggestion my dear Friends...

Comment: Search for floating element. I'm sure you will find solution.

Comment: That actually is the right side..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `FrameLayout`:

```
<FrameLayout
    ... >

    <ListView
        ... />

    <Button
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
        ... />

</FrameLayout>
```